# How to select a div that have no any attribute and contain specific child with Jsoup?

Tags: jsoup

I want to select the follwoing html.  div that have no any attribute and contain img and a child. Thanks in advance.

```html
<div>
  date：
 <img src="http:XXXXX" hspace="2" vspace="0"> 
 <a href="/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/">today</a> 
 <img src="http:XXXXX" hspace="2" vspace="0">
 <a href="/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/20151102/"> 11/02 </a> 
 <img src="http:XXXXX" hspace="2" vspace="0">
 <a href="/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/20151103/"> 11/03 </a>      
</div>
```

Comment: why would doc.select("div") not do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you.

```
Elements elements = doc.select("div");

for(Element element : elements){

    if(element.attributes().size() > 0 || element.select("img").size() == 0){

        elements.remove(element);

    }   
}
```